# How to check condition before loading a tab in bottomTabNavigator react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

As stated in the title, i want to check first if some data is loaded before showing a **clicked** tab, if the data is not there show alert and don't show tab.
I need to know where to implement this logic. 
THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a listner for the same, in the tab screen, whenever you tab is clicked then

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions, NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation'

<NavigationEvents
  onWillFocus={payload => {
    this.checkIfUserRegistered();
  }}
//onDidFocus={payload => console.log('did focus', payload)}
//onWillBlur={payload => console.warn('will blur', payload)}
//onDidBlur={payload => console.log('did blur', payload)}
/>
```

Your render funtion looks like this,

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationEvents
        onWillFocus={payload => {
          this.checkIfUserRegistered(); 
           # common component, if unregistered then you can go back to the screen which you want to display
        }}
      //onDidFocus={payload => console.log('did focus', payload)}
      //onWillBlur={payload => console.warn('will blur', payload)}
      //onDidBlur={payload => console.log('did blur', payload)}
      />
    </View >
  );

}
```

More you can read [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) for navigation events ..

I hope it helps thanks .... :)

Comment: you can accept the answer as well if it works for you....Thanks :)